# AWS S3 how to set access_key, secret_access_key and session_token in my node js app so they don't change

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3

I deployed my backend app (node js), but I'm new to AWS S3 and don't really get the concept of credentials, so now that it's deployed the credentials expired (sessionToken) and the site doesn't work like before. I'm aware I used short-term credentials, but I don't see what else I could use. Did I need use long-term (I thought they were not recommended to use?) I'm using s3-proxy and multer-s3 for storing and serving files (images) from my bucket.

How do I make credentials in AWS S3 not change, so my app keeps working?

```
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require("uuid");
require("dotenv").config();

const { S3Client } = require("@aws-sdk/client-s3");
const multerS3 = require("multer-s3");

const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const multer = require("multer");

const cors = require("cors");

const { graphqlHTTP } = require("express-graphql");
const schema = require("./util/schema");
const resolver = require("./util/resolver");
const isAuth = require("./middleware/isAuth");
const s3Proxy = require("s3-proxy");

const app = express();

const s3 = new S3Client({
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    sessionToken: process.env.AWS_SESSION_TOKEN,
  },
  region: "eu-central-1",
});

app.options("*", cors());
app.use(cors());

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


const upload = multer({
  storage: multerS3({
    s3: s3,
    bucket: "express-app-recipe",
    metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, { fieldName: file.fieldname });
    },
    key: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, uuidv4());
    },
  }),
});

app.use(
  "/images/",
  s3Proxy({
    bucket: "express-app-recipe",
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    sessionToken: process.env.AWS_SESSION_TOKEN,
  })
);

app.use(isAuth);

app.post("/post-image", upload.single("image"), (req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.isAuth) {
    const error = new Error("Not authenticated");
    error.statusCode = 401;
    throw error;
  }

  if (!req.file) {
    const error = new Error("No file attached!");
    error.statusCode = 400;
    throw error;
  }


  return res.status(201).send({
    message: "File recieved",
    filePath: req.file.key,
  });
});

app.use(
  "/graphql",
  graphqlHTTP({
    schema: schema,
    rootValue: resolver,
    graphiql: true,
    customFormatErrorFn(err) {
      if (!err.originalError) {
        return err;
      }
      const data = err.originalError.data; 
      const message = err.message || "An error occured";
      const code = err.originalError.code;

      return { message: message, status: code, data: data };
    },
  })
);

app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
  console.log(error);
  const status = error.statusCode;
  const data = error.data;
  const message = error.message;
  res.status(status).json({ message: message, data: data });
});

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.DB_CONN)
  .then((result) => {
    app.listen(process.env.PORT);
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is an EC2 instance, then launch the instance with an appropriately-configured IAM role. The node app's AWS SDK will then fetch temporary credentials, as needed, and auto-rotate them before they expire.

Also, change your client, as follows, to allow the SDK to automatically fetch the credentials:

```
const s3 = new S3Client({region:"eu-central-1"});
```

See [Using an IAM role to grant permissions to applications running on Amazon EC2 instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2.html).

If running on a compute platform outside of AWS then things are a little different. The primary solution for that is [IAM Roles Anywhere](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rolesanywhere/latest/userguide/introduction.html):

> You can use AWS Identity and Access Management Roles Anywhere to obtain temporary security credentials in IAM for workloads such as servers, containers, and applications that run outside of AWS. Your workloads can use the same IAM policies and IAM roles that you use with AWS applications to access AWS resources. Using IAM Roles Anywhere means you don't need to manage long-term credentials for workloads running outside of AWS.

The way this works is that IAM Roles Anywhere relies on public key infrastructure (PKI) to establish trust between your AWS account and certificate authority (CA) that issues certificates to your on-premises workloads. Your workloads outside of AWS use IAM Roles Anywhere to exchange X.509 certificates for temporary AWS credentials.

Comment: This is not an EC2 instance.